How to implement pagination for the app similar to reddit
I have been developing something similar to reddit but have been stuck on pagination of comments for more than a week.
I have the following model for comment:
model Comment {
  id              String    @id @default(uuid())
  postId          String
  authorId        String
  content         String
  createdAt       DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt       DateTime  @updatedAt
  upvotes         Int       @default(0)
  downvotes       Int       @default(0)
  parentCommentId String?
  path            String    // Materialized path
  depth           Int       // Comment depth
  isDeleted       Boolean   @default(false)
  childCount      Int       @default(0) // New field to track number of direct children
  author          User      @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  parentComment   Comment?  @relation("CommentReplies", fields: [parentCommentId], references: [id])
  replies         Comment[] @relation("CommentReplies")
  post            Post      @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
  votes           Vote[]
}

To get comments of a post, i have to paginate. Initially, 20 root comments with some child comments. But for the next load, I could not find a method to fetch comments without refetching the ones already fetched or missing some of the comments in case they got a lot of upvotes between requests.
I have tried cursor based pagination but it does not satisfy the requirements mentioned above. Only valid way i can think of is to store the id of comment already fetched and sort the other ones and return.

It's prisma model, isn't it? Then the question is very specific to it. You should mention this. Also the question isn't specific enough, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . "I have tried cursor based pagination" - what did you try? "  it does not satisfy the requirements" - which ones?
